# plain C: opening a directory with fopen()

Tags: c, linux, types, io

I have a program which opens a file and checks its length.

```
FILE* fd = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t flen = ftell(fd);
if (flen == ((size_t)-1)) {
    printf("%s is a directory.\n", argv[1]);
    fclose(fd);
    exit(1);
}
```

Now, at least under Linux, `fopen()` returns a valid file descriptor when opening a directory. This results in the seek operation returning `-1` (or, as `size_t` is unsigned, `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`=2<sup>64</sup>-1 on a 64-bit system).

Unfortunately, the condition in the above code (`flen == ((size_t)-1)`) does not catch that case, neither does `flen == 0xFFFFFFFF` (EDIT: should be `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`). `printf()`-Commands with `%x` ord `%d` as format string show that both sides of the comparison should have the same value.

Why does the comparison operator behave in such a strange way, even when both sides are of the same type (`size_t`)? I am using gcc 4.8.1 as compiler.

Comment: Don't you mean `sizeof(size_t)-1` ?

Comment: @ScottyBauer No, he doesn't.

Comment: Also, `FILE fd` shall be `FILE *fd`. And `ftell()` doesn't return `size_t` but `long`. And -1 is not `0xFFFFFFFF` on 64-bit (assuming 2's complement), but `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @H2CO3 I am not familiar with that statement, what does it mean? Specifically the `flen == ((size_t)-1)`

Comment: @ScottyBauer Google "C type casting".

Comment: You can `open()` a directory (and hence `fopen()` it), but that's about all you can do with it.  The intent is to allow you to use `fchdir()` on the file descriptor.  For reading the directory, you need to use `opendir()`, `readdir()`, etc.  For finding its size, you could use `fstat(fileno(fd))` — though using the name `fd` for a `FILE *` instead of a file descriptor strikes me as rotten naming (I'd use `FILE *fp = fopen("file", "r"); int fd = fileno(fp);`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Directories do not exist in the C99 standard (or the C2011 one). So by definition, `fopen`-ing a directory is either implementation specific or undefined behavior.

[fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) can fail (giving a `NULL` result). [fseek(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) can also fail (by returning -1). And then you should preferably check [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) or use [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html)

`ftell` is documented to return a `long`, and `-1L` on failure. On 64 bits Linux this is `0xffffffffffffffff`.

You code should be instead

```
FILE* fd = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
if (!fd) 
  { perror(argv[1]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
if (fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)<0) 
  { perror("fseek"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
long flen = ftell(fd);
if (flen == -1L)
  { perror("ftell"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

<sup>BTW, On Linux/Debian/Sid/AMD64 with libc-2.17 and 3.10.6 kernel, that codes runs ok when `argv[1]` is `/tmp`; surprizingly, `flen` is `LONG_MAX` i.e. `0x7fffffffffffffff`</sup>

BTW, on Linux, directories are a special case of files. Use [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) on a file path (and `fstat` on a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), perhaps obtained with [fileno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) from some `FILE*`) to know more meta data about some file, including its "type" (thru its mode). You want [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) & [closedir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html) to operate on directory contents. See also [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html).

Comment: Thank you, I've solved it now by changing the type of flen to `int32_t`, which works well on 32- and 64-bit systems (using `long` did not work on 64-bit systems).

Answer (score 9):

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fopen.html:

```
The fopen() function will fail if: 
[EISDIR] The named file is a directory and mode requires write access.
```

At least on Linux, if you try to `fopen("dirname", "wb")` you get an EISDIR error. I also tried with a directory with d-------- access rights, and I still get EISDIR (and not EACCES.)