# How does fchdir work?

Tags: c, chdir

In it's main page it says:

> fchdir() is identical to chdir(); the only difference is that the
>   directory is given as an open file descriptor.

And the prototype is given as following:

> int chdir(const char *path);
>   int fchdir(int fd);

My question is how can a directory be passed as a file descriptor? Do directories also have a corresponding descriptor like files?

Comment: no answer but maybe interesting for  you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file

Comment: You have some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192998/plain-c-opening-a-directory-with-fopen

Comment: Also if you have used `opendir` to open the directory, you can get the file descriptor from the `DIR *` with `dirfd()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do directories also have a corresponding descriptor like files?

Yes. The Unix philosophy(and Linux) is to treat everything as a stream of bytes. So yes, you can do `open(2)` on a directory and get its file descriptor.
Not only directories but sockets, pipes and devices can also be opened using `open(2)` system call and do operations on it as though it's a file.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read on [the Opengroup documentation for `fchdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchdir.html),

> A conforming application can obtain a file descriptor for a file of type directory using open(), provided that the file status flags and access modes do not contain O_WRONLY or O_RDWR.

So by calling `open` on a directory, one obtains a file descriptor to a directory. So in a sense, yes, all directories have file descriptors.

The underlying OS takes care to map the file descriptors to the proper filesystem object, thus abstracting away whatever this object may be at the lowest level.