# NULL memories entry

Tags: c

I wrote this little program that reads a file in binary form (Databases.db in this example) and copies its content in the cpydatabases.db...

When I run the debugger in the `fopen_s(&source, "Databases.db", "r");`, the `source` is always `NULL` (while debugging it shows that the memory entry is always `Null, 0x000000000000 <NULL>`).

This program runs in visual studio 2015.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dirent.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 2048
char ch, *readbuf;
int nread, nwrit;
FILE *source, *target;

int main()
{
    int returnv;
    fopen_s(&source, "Databases.db", "r");

    if ( source !== NULL)
    {
        fclose(source);
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fopen_s(&target,"cpydatabases.db", "w");
    //check again
    if (target == NULL)
    {
        fclose(target);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //setting the char that reads the binary
    readbuf = (char *)malloc(BUFFSIZE* sizeof(char));

    if (readbuf == NULL)
    {
        fclose(source);
        fclose(target);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        nread = fread((void *)readbuf, sizeof(char), BUFFSIZE, source) ;
        // fwrite((void *)readbuf, sizeof(char), nread, target);
        nwrit = fwrite((void *)readbuf, sizeof(char), nread, target);
        if (nwrit < nread)
        {
            returnv = (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (nread <= BUFFSIZE)
        { 
            returnv = (EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        }    
    }

    fclose(source);
    fclose(target);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the return of `fopen_s` function calls? If `source` is `NULL`, you must not `close()` it.

Comment: Check the msdn example for the return value of fopen_s https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx

Comment: Are the files located in the same folder as the executable?

Comment: Note: the memory you've `malloc`ated is not `free`d.

Comment: Why can't you use `fopen` and, when it fails, use `perror`? Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18193383/841108)?

Comment: i used the perror in my code returning erron n16 which is my exact problem...

Comment: i think https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktss1a9b.aspx link might be useful.

Comment: Files that are opened by fopen_s and _wfopen_s are not sharable. If you require that a file be sharable, use _fsopen, _wfsopen with the appropriate sharing mode constant—for example, _SH_DENYNO for read/write sharing.

Comment: this didn't work either...the dublicated file is still null

Comment: this code block: `    if ( source !== NULL)
    {
        fclose(source);
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }` is not correct: it will exit immediately when ever the input file was successfully opened.  Suggest: `    if ( source == NULL)
    {
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }` so only exits if `fopen()` fails

Comment: the code block: `    if (target == NULL)
    {
        fclose(target);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }` is not correct,  The is NOT open, so no need to close it.  However, the source is open, so it needs to be closed.  Suggest: `    if (target == NULL)
    {
        fclose(source);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }`

Comment: When a system function, such as: `fopen()` fails, an error message should be output to stderr that contains why the system/OS thinks the call failed.  The easiest way to do that is to insert the statement: `perror( "fopen failed for source" );   before any other statements in the error handling code

Comment: in C, the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) return type is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  The expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Using that expression in the parameter to `malloc()` just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: in general, it is a bad programming paradigm to use global variables when those variables will not be used in another file.  Suggest moving them to local variables, on the stack inside the `main()` function

Comment: the posted code sets the variable `returnv` in a number of places, but never uses that value.   When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings

Comment: when calling `fread()` (and usually when calling `fwrite()`) always check the returned value to note how many of the second parameter size 'objects' were actually read.

Comment: the returned values from `fread()` and `fwrite()` should be check to be >= 0.  and if <0 then handle the error

Comment: this code block: `if (nread <= BUFFSIZE)
        { 
            returnv = (EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        }` say that if the read were successful (or an error occurred) then exit the read/write loop.  Not what the code really wants to do.  A read count of 0 indicates EOF and then you would want to exit the read/write loop.

Comment: the function: `fopen_s()` is MSN specific (I.E. Not portable)  Suggest adding `#define _crt_secure_no_warnings` at the top of the file and then using `fopen()` rather than `fopen_s()`  so your code will be portable.

Comment: thank you very much man you've been like extra helpfull!!! i'll arrange my project to your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. You should have your Databases.db file in the same folder as your source.cpp file, or use an absolute path like "C:/Databases". Anyway this code worked for me:

```
#define BUFFSIZE 2048
char ch, source_file[50], target_file[50], *readbuf;
int nread, nwrit;

FILE *source, *target;
int main()
{

    int returnv;
    fopen_s(&source, "Databases.db", "r");

    if (source == NULL)
    {
        //fclose(source);
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fopen_s(&target, "cpydatabases.db", "w");
    //check again
    if (target == NULL)
    {
        fclose(target);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: Probably should be `==`, as he does with `target`. But the `fclose` should not be there.

Comment: Yes, i saw that eventually :)

Comment: my "cpydatabases.db" is not the same size ( 7KB the Databases, 2KB the cpydatabases)...the code works but i cant figure out what's going wrong in the &source memory address and why is it null

Comment: the two arrays: `source_file[]` and `target_file[]` are unused.  the statement: `fclose( target );` should be saying: `fclose( source );`

Comment: yeap they are leftovers of the last update i did to the code...sorry for posting them

Comment: The reason why the cpydatabases file is 2KB is because you have set the maximum #BUFFERSIZE to "2048", which is 2KB. You should increase that if you want bigger files than 2KB.

Comment: Instead using a define for size buffer, you could I guess calculate the size of the source file. For example like this:

 int calcSize(FILE *fp) {
 int prev = ftell(fp);
 fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
 int size = ftell(fp);
 fseek(fp, prev, SEEK_SET); //go back to where we were
 return size;
}

Answer (score 0):

I think "Databases.db" is in not in same directory where executable is. 
You can give complete path of "Databases.db" or copy this file where your `.sln` file is.

Comment: i have placed the file in the same dir with the .exe but still the same problem