# slurmctld: fatal: CLUSTER NAME MISMATCH

Tags: slurm

The way I start slurm:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/slurmstate/clustername
sudo slurmd
sudo munged -f
/etc/init.d/munge start 
sudo slurmdbd
sudo slurmctld -c
```

-

```
sacctmgr list cluster
   Cluster     ControlHost  ControlPort   RPC     Share GrpJobs       GrpTRES GrpSubmit MaxJobs       MaxTRES MaxSubmit     MaxWall                  QOS   Def QOS
---------- --------------- ------------ ----- --------- ------- ------------- --------- ------- ------------- --------- ----------- -------------------- ---------
   cluster                            0  7936         1                                                                                           normal
```

Running `slurmctld -cD` gives me following error. Cluster name returns some invalid string that I don't know. How could I fix it?

```
> slurmctld -cD
slurmctld: fatal: CLUSTER NAME MISMATCH.
slurmctld has been started with "ClusterName=�����", but read "cluster" from the state files in StateSaveLocation.
Running multiple clusters from a shared StateSaveLocation WILL CAUSE CORRUPTION.
Remove /tmp/slurmstate/clustername to override this safety check if this is intentional (e.g., the ClusterName has changed).
```

Note: When I try to run slurm as root user and switch back, this problem start occurring. I had to re-install mysql to make it fix.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: You could check the value of `ClusterName ` in `slurm.conf` and make sure the encoding of that file is correct.

Comment: Actually it is on the `slurm.conf file` as `ClusterName=cluster`. @ damienfrancois

Comment: 1) Why do you create `/tmp/slurmstate/clustername` as a directory (from your latest edit)? --- 2) I think the error message is incorrect, if I read [the source code correctly](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/slurm-17-02-4-1/src/slurmctld/controller.c#L2634-L2643), the non-printable characters were found in state file, not in `slurm.conf` (the error is real but the message unfortunately switches the values)

Comment: Oh... then let's undelete my answer that I thought was just noise :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>I'm a complete SLURM noob (just started taking interest in it for work), so apologies if I make misguided suggestions, but I think I can point at something wrong.</sup>

First line in your startup sequence:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/slurmstate/clustername
```

So you create a directory here, I mean `clustername` is a *directory*.

When the daemon starts, it tries to read this *as a file* ([using `fopen` and `fgets`, see source code of latest version](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/slurm-17-02-4-1/src/slurmctld/controller.c#L2621-L2647)).

And then, since [the behavior of `fopen`-ing a directory is system-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193383/6730571), anything can happen (it could read garbage, or fail...). It would be interesting if you could specify what OS you are using.

Suggestion:

- `rmdir /tmp/slurmstate/clustername`
- replace your first line with `mkdir -p /tmp/slurmstate`, to create the `slurmstate` directory if it does not exist, but do not create a `clustername` file (or directory!) yourself in there.

First time it will create the `clustername` file, and write in there the name as taken from your `slurm.conf` file. Subsequent startups will read the value from the file and compare it from the one in `slurm.conf`, and move on with the startup.

PS : I just noticed that you added that line in your last edit, so **you had the root problem before doing that**... so the problem I'm pointing at is probably nothing. Maybe I should remove that answer (again) (but maybe your question will need another edit).