# segmentation fault(core dumped) in C in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, fault

[image]

This is main.c

[image]

This is print.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int wc(FILE *pointer)
{ 
  int a;
  int character=0,word=0,line=0;
  a = getc(pointer);
  while ( a != EOF )
  { 
    character++;
    if (a == ' ')
      word++;
    if (a == '\n')
       line++;
    a = getc(pointer);
  }

  printf("character: %4d, word: %4d, line: %4d \n", character,word,line);
  return 0;
}
```

This is word.c

```
gcc -c print.c
gcc -c word.c
gcc -c main.c
gcc -o main main.o print.o word.o
./main
text.txt
text.txt
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is compile ways that i used.

But I don't know why I have segmentation fault(core dumped).

Please help me.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then use the debugger `gdb`; your fix-my-code question is off-topic. Read about every standard function you are using: [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) -and many other functions- can fail. Test that it does not like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193383/841108)

Comment: Posting the text instead of images of it would've been better.

Comment: For one thing, you open the file twice without closing it in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main()`, you should check if the `fopen()` were successful by seeing if the return value is `NULL` in which case an error occurred.

Also, you are using `argv[1]` even if the condition `argc>1` is not satisfied with the second `fopen()` in `main()`. `argv[1]` won't be there if `argc` is less than `2`.

In the `while` loop in `printfile()`, the `break` statement would be executed on the first iteration itself.

So making that `while` into an `if` statement and removing the `break` would have the same effect.

In the `while` loop of `wc()`,

```
if (a == ' ')
  word++;
if (a == '\n')
   line++;
```

could be made

```
if (a == ' ')
  word++;
else if (a == '\n')
   line++;
```

No need to check if `a` is `\n` if `a` is (space).

Edit: And don't forget to close all the files you've opened once you are done using them.

Comment: I am poor at English and C programming yet. I understood your comment many things but, I didn't understand just one thing about fclose()...                 If you are okay, Can you teach me where I should use fclose() in my code...?

Comment: @Huitseize As soon as you are finished using a file. If you still need the file but need to open another, use a _different_ file pointer to open it.

Comment: @Huitseize If you remove the second `fopen()` in `main()`, your usage of `fclose()` seems appropriate.