# Function for loading data from binary files to array of structs

Tags: c

This is my code for loading data from  binary file to array of structs but I get error that file is not found. File is there and it works with other functions.

```
void ispis2(void) {
    float data_num = brojanje();
    int N = data_num / 3;
    ARTIKL artikl[120];
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("artikli.bin", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pogreska: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            fread(&artikl[i].ime, sizeof(artikl), 1, fp);
            fread(&artikl[i].cijena, sizeof(artikl), 1, fp);
            fread(&artikl[i].ID, sizeof(artikl), 1, fp);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            printf("Ime: %s", artikl[i].ime);
            printf("Cijena: %f", artikl[i].cijena);
            printf("ID: %d", artikl[i].ID);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The file is not there where you think it is, check where your program runs. Tell us more about your platform/IDE/compiler etc.

Comment: Double check the file name and use the full path as necessary.

Comment: This: `fread(&artikl[i].ime, sizeof(artikl), 1, fp);` looks very suspicious, as it's basically saying that the single field `ime` has the same size as the entire array of 120 `ARTIKL`s. That makes no sense, since the field is in one element of that array. You probably meant `sizeof artikl[i].ime`.

Comment: Your question should have some [MCVE] and is not one since we don't know what is `ARTIKL`

Comment: I am using sam file for function that writes into binary file and works perfectly. ARTIKL is a struct.
I adjusted fread to sizeof artikl[i].ime and it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are not running your program in the environment (notably check the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)) you want.

Of course your `fread`-s smell bad. Read again the documentation of [standard C input/output](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) functions, in particular of [fread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread). The `sizeof(artikl)` argument is surely wrong (but since your question don't explain what an `ARTIKL` really is, we cannot help more).

The notion of [directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)) is unknown by the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193383/841108). But if you are on a POSIX system, you could query it with [getcwd(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html). Other operating systems have different ways of querying it (e.g. [GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows). Read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to understand more about operating systems, and read also a good C programming book.

So you could perhaps improve the error handling:

```
if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Pogreska: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    char wdbuf[128];
    memset(wdbuf, 0, sizeof(cwdbuf));
    fprintf(stderr, "working directory: %s\n", 
            getcwd(wdbuf, sizeof(wdbuf));
}
```

(the above code don't handle failure of `getcwd`; a robust program should handle that)

BTW, I am not sure that handling binary files like you do is worthwhile (a binary format is *very* brittle, and you need to document its format very precisely; remember that most of the time, data is more valuable than the application processing it). You might consider instead storing the data in some textual format (like [JSON](http://json.org/), [YAML](http://yaml.org/), ....) or in some [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) database. Consider using appropriate libraries (e.g. [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) for JSON, `libsqlite` [for](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) sqlite)

Don't forget to compile your code with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Read the documentation of your compiler (e.g. how to [invoke it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)) and of your [debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Use the debugger to understand the behavior of your program.

Comment: This is project for school and I am trying to make cash register. I need to have it done today so if you can help in any way I would be grateful.
I am using visual studio 2017 and that binary file is something like a database for all items in store.

Comment: You won't do it for today. You are late, and there are some basic concepts of C programming that you still don't understand. I'm sorry about that, but we cannot really help! For your next school project, put more time and efforts in it. BTW, StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* site

Comment: I need to have some kind of cash register program today.
Do you at least have an idea for simple version of that?

Comment: No, you believe I will do your homework. But I won't. I'm probably older than your father, and I did taught at university, so I understand the importance that students write their program on their own. See http://norvig.com/21-days.html ; next time, work more!

Comment: Then my answer should be enough. Of course you need to spend a few days reading some good C programming book, and reading the documentation of every function that you are using